# how can run ant command in php to generate .apk file

Tags: php, android, xml

i run command command

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ant release');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

the output is :

Buildfile: /var/www/project_name/build.xml

but the .apk file is not generated but when i run ant release command at terminal .apk file generated.
what is my mistake to run ant command in php